# How do I run a user-installed Ruby gem as a different user?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've set up a hook as that runs fine as one of my regular users, with the required gems installed under that user using `gem install --user-install`.  Now I want to run the hook as a different user, but when I try it, ruby can't find the installed gems:

```
$ /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/jekyll
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find jekyll (>= 0) amongst [rack-1.5.2, rack-protection-1.5.0, ruby-openid-2.1.8, sinatra-1.0, tilt-1.3.6] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin/jekyll:18:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let Ruby know where its gems are installed.  The environment `GEM_HOME` controls this, so you can do something like this:

```
export GEM_HOME=/home/user/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
$GEM_HOME/bin/jekyll help
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to install for one user and run under another, install for all users.

On a shared-environment host, you, if you have "sudo" capability, or the system administrator, can do a normal `sudo gem install ...` to install globally for everyone.

A normal Ruby installation works that way.

Often, as developers, we want to run Ruby in our own personal sandbox, so we can change and install Ruby versions and load different versions of gems without it affecting others on the box.

Once the code is ready for testing and production, we want it in a shared environment, so we only have a single Ruby installation shared among all apps, which usually run as the same user. Even if the apps run as different users, they still use the same Ruby.

They do this via the default environment and path. If this doesn't make sense, talk to a system administrator.